# Different display modi by multiple events

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

I wanted on different events, different display modi:

```
.on("enter leave", function (e) {
    $("#artwork figcaption").style.display(e.type == "none" ? "block" : "none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting styles this way i suggest you to use `.css()`:

```
.on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    $("#artwork figcaption").css("display", e.type == "mouseenter" ? "block" : "none");
});
```

or using a callback in `.css()`:

```
.on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    $("#artwork figcaption").css("display", function(){
        return e.type == "mouseenter" ? "block" : "none";
    });
});
```

Comment: to use .css was correct, you were right with the event condition, I haven't seen it. I figured out as a result now:   
.on("enter leave", function (e) {
  $("#artwork figcaption").css(e.type == "enter" ? {display:"block"} : {display:"none"});
  });